# How can I search on "/" and "$" in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to add a NOT condition to a Sphinx search:

```
!($|/) NEAR/3 (HR)
```

however Sphinx returns  "unexpected $" or  "unexpected /" so I am assuming those are characters used as syntax searches. How can I tell Sphinx for this search to use as characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape those symbols using `\\`:

```
select * from my_index where match('!(\\$|\\/) NEAR/3 (HR)');
```

Comment: @BarryHunter. That escapes them w/o error yet it doesn't eliminate results like '$90 hr' and in fact if I change to (\\$|\\/) NEAR/3 (HR) in other words without the ! it still finds it. So it seems to be escaping $ and / but to the point they aren't recognized, not to the point the are recognized as characters.

Comment: Well remember sphinx only matches whole words. But also not sure that your query makes sence sphinx a 'not' near something. I think you want `!(word NEAR word)` rather than `!word NEAR word`